# not able to close warning PopUp using JavaScript 

Tags: javascript, jsp

i have a jsp in which i have used **scriptlets**. it generates warning message PopUp and get close when session expires. my jsp is as follows:

```
     <%@  taglib   prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>


    <%@  page language="java" contentType="text/html"%>
    <%@ session ="false" %>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function close() { 
       var userSessionExpire= "<%= request.getParameter("sessionExpire") %>";
        if(userSessionExpire !=null && userSessionExpire ="true" ){
          open('', 'SessionWarning').close();
      }
      }
    </script>
    </head>
```

when i removed **scriplet** and use **JSTL** and **EL.** warning PopUp generates but this window is not getting close with session Expiry.changes are as below:

```
         function close(){
        <c:set var="sess"  value="${param.sessionExpire}" />  
         if(sess !=null && sess ="true" ){
         open('', 'SessionWarning').close();
      } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing the nature of JavaScript and Java/JSP. They do not run in sync. You need to realize that Java/JSP runs in webserver and generates HTML/CSS/JS code upon a HTTP request and that the webbrowser will display the HTML, apply the CSS and execute the JS upon a HTTP response.

You need to let Java/JSP generate JS code accordingly that it has valid syntax. With your approach,

```
function close() {
    <c:set var="sess"  value="${param.sessionExpire}" />  
    if (sess != null && sess = "true") {
        open('', 'SessionWarning').close();
    }
}
```

the generated JS code will look like this (rightclick and *View Source* in webbrowser):

```
function close() {

    if (sess != null && sess = "true") {
        open('', 'SessionWarning').close();
    }
}
```

This is not right. You want it to look like as follows:

```
function close() {
    var sess = true; // Or var sess = false;
    if (sess) {
        open('', 'SessionWarning').close();
    }
}
```

*(please note that I fixed your `if` condition, the `sess="true"` does not do what you think!)*

So, you need to rewrite your JSP as follows:

```
function close() {
    var sess = ${not empty param.sessionExpire and param.sessionExpire};
    if (sess) {
        open('', 'SessionWarning').close();
    }
}
```

The difference between EL and *Scriptlets* is that EL does not print `null` when the value is `null`, but instead an empty string. Hence the additional `not empty` check so that the whole EL expression prints a fullworthy boolean value `true` or `false`.

The above can also be simplified as follows:

```
function close() {
    if (${not empty param.sessionExpire and param.sessionExpire}) {
        open('', 'SessionWarning').close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC, these are very much helpful tips you suggested. thanks a lot!!